# How to convert clob to string using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

i want to select data from a table with datatype clob.
so the resut is like oracle.sql.CLOB@12fe54d
I want to display the data as string as they appear in the table.

in groovy i tried this:

```
rowTest = sql.firstRow("select name from table where id=10")
clobTest = (oracle.sql.CLOB)rowTest[0]

byte_stream_test = clobTest.getBinaryStream()
if( byte_stream_test == null ) {  println "Test: Received null stream!"  }

byte[] byte_array_test = new byte[10]
int bytes_read_test = byte_stream_test.read(byte_array_test)

print "Read $bytes_read_test bytes from the clob!"

sql.connection.close()
```

I have the following error:

```
---- A working test of writing and then reading a blob into an Oracle DB ---
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: oracle.sql.CLOB.getBinaryStream() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at Test2.run(Test2.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:884)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at Test2.main(Test2.groovy)
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem, thank you

Comment: have you tried looking at the JavaDaoc for CLOB http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/sql/CLOB.html ?

Answer (score 15):

Try the following code:

```
  rowTest = sql.firstRow("select name from table where id=10")
  clobTest = (oracle.sql.CLOB)rowTest[0]
  bodyText = clobTest?.asciiStream.text
  println bodyText
```

Comment: I tried the above code and i cannot see the output and there is no error message now, Where is the Log output content.

Comment: clobTest? means that .asciiStream.text will be executed if clobTest is not null. Since you are not getting anything on output I guess that clobTest is actually null. Remove ? and test it.

Answer (score 2):

Use characterStream instead of asciiStream to support Unicode characters:

```
String unicode = "äö"
Clob clob = new ClobImpl(unicode)
String strClob = clob?.characterStream?.text
assertEquals(strClob, unicode)
```